# On the proof of Lucas' theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Lucas theorem states that

Let $m,n$ be two natural numbers, $p$ be a prime. Suppose that  $m, n$ admit the following base $p$ representation
$$m=m_0+m_1p+\cdots+m_sp^s,\qquad n=n_0+n_1p+\cdots+n_sp^s$$
with $0\le m_i, n_i \le p-1$, then
$$\binom{n}{m}\equiv\prod_{i=0}^{s}\binom{n_i}{m_i}\ (\bmod p)$$

I have read the proof of Lucas' Theorem on Wikipedia and [in this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.3820v1.pdf). There are some steps that I don't fully understand. It is follows

\begin{align*}
\sum^{n}_{m=0}\binom{n}{m}X^m&=(1+X)^n=\prod_{i=0}^{s}\left( (1+X)^{p^i}\right)^{n_i}\\
&\equiv \prod_{i=0}^{s}(1+X^{p^i})^{n_i}=\prod_{i=0}^{s}\left( \sum_{m_i=0}^{n_i}\binom{n_i}{m_i}X^{m_ip^i}\right)\ (\bmod p)\\
&=\prod_{i=0}^{s}\left(\sum_{m_i=0}^{p-1}\binom{n_i}{m_i}X^{m_ip^i} \right)\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{n}\left(\prod_{i=0}^{s}\binom{n_i}{m_i} \right)X^m\ (\bmod p)
\end{align*}

How can we get \begin{align*}
&\prod_{i=0}^{s}\left( \sum_{m_i=0}^{n_i}\binom{n_i}{m_i}X^{m_ip^i}\right) \\
&=\prod_{i=0}^{s}\left(\sum_{m_i=0}^{p-1}\binom{n_i}{m_i}X^{m_ip^i} \right)\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{n}\left(\prod_{i=0}^{s}\binom{n_i}{m_i} \right)X^m
\end{align*}

I don't know how can we change the index from $n_i$ to $p-1$ in the first equation and how can we get the second equation.

Please explain for me.

Thanks

Comment: $m_i$ has two different meanings: In some places it's a constant depending on $m$; in other places it's a variable being summed over, and may as well be called $k$.

Answer (score 1):

For the first line, observe that 
$${n_i\choose k}=0$$ 
for $k>n_i$. So, 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{m_i=0}^{n_i}\binom{n_i}{m_i}X^{m_ip^i} =\sum_{m_i=0}^{p-1}\binom{n_i}{m_i}X^{m_ip^i}
\end{align*}
, as the extra terms are basically zero.

For the second line, notice that $m$ can be uniquely written in the form 
$$m_0'+m_1'p+\ldots+m_s'p^s$$

Thus, the coefficient of $X^m$ in 
\begin{align*}
\prod_{i=0}^{s}\left(\sum_{m_i=0}^{p-1}\binom{n_i}{m_i}X^{m_ip^i} \right)
\end{align*}
will be the product of the coefficients of $X^{m_ip^i}$.